# Catch phrase/idiom/slang for every bad thing happens for a good reason

Tags: idioms, slang, catch-phrases

Is there any catch-phrase/idiom/slang I can use to express that every bad thing happens for a good reason? (or that bad things could lead to good consequences eventually)?

Comment: Say it in Latin, ***omnia causa fiunt***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***[blessing in disguise](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/a-blessing-in-disguise)*** conveys the idea that an initial negative  fact or experience may actually result in something positive: 
​

> - something that seems bad or unlucky at first, but results in something good happening later:
>     *Losing that job was a blessing in disguise really.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

See **every cloud has a silver lining** at [the free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Every+cloud+has+a+silver+lining)

> something that you say which means that there is something good even in an unpleasant situation

There is also the commonly understood **rainbow after the rain** or **for a rainbow, it has to rain first**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56419/discussion-on-answer-by-vickyace-catch-phrase-idiom-slang-for-every-bad-thing-ha).